# Railstutorial - App is working fine on local server but when I push to heroku I get application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm doing the railstutorial by mike hartl and so far it's going well. How ever I'm stuck on lesson 7 conclusion.

I have basically got everything working, all rsync tests are passing and everything is working. I commit and push to GIT then push to heroko.

I use heroku open to open my app and the page that comes up gives me application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

**Here are my heroku logs:**

```
[sample_app (master)]$ heroku logs
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `ev

2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2011-07-08T12:08:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-07-08T12:08:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-07-08T12:18:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-07-08T12:18:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-07-08T12:18:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 16326 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': Missing helper file helpers/factory_girl.rb (LoadError)
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:101:in `modules_for_helpers'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:97:in `helper'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:228:in `inherited'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-07-08T12:18:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-07-08T12:28:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-07-08T12:28:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-07-08T12:28:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 51125 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- factory_girl (LoadError)
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'


2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-07-08T12:28:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-07-08T12:28:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have your factory_girl.rb in the helpers directory? Is your Gemfile up2date?
It may be possible it's not tracked yet, thus your push ignored it.

Comment: Hmm there's no factory_girl in my helpers directory. I thought it is automatically done on bundle install. I added this: require 'factory_girl'
Factory.find_definitions to my users_helper and that was what stopped my factory_girl error earlier in the tutorial. My gemfile is up2date. Rubymine notifies me if it isn't.

Comment: No, the factory_girl helper you create manually. Last time I worked with it, about 2 months ago, it wasn't one of the generated files. Search for an example on the railscasts page.

Comment: In the sample_app for this tutorial nothing was said about factory_girl helper. Also I've check on GIT and there is no factory_girl helper.